# Rails, Paperclip, and load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, load-balancing

I was ok using Paperclip plugin for my Rails app to manage my user's avatar images on file system.

Now I have to do load balance, which force me to put image somewhere central to be shared to multiple servers.

I found out Paperclip can not go to custom asset host. Paperclip can do S3, but i'm seeking alternate way by not using S3. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 2):

Paperclip supports Fog, see /lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb and http://fog.io.  From their website:

> Whether you need compute, dns, storage, or a multitude of other services, fog provides an accessible entry point and facilitates cross service compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) to upload to S3, since our host, [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) only allows storing files remotely. However, you can also use Carrierwave to upload to other storage services like Rackspace. Initially and like you, I had issues with load balancing. Since uploading a file would, in theory, hang the application until the upload is finished.

I found a way around this by uploading directly to our storage service using javascript. I used [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for this specifically. Uploading directly does not take up a entire http thread which pretty much evens out the load balance on the server.

What I would suggest, if you still decide on using Paperclip, is to upload directly to a storage service (or even your own server, if your server host allows it), using javascript and then assigning the file to your Paperclip uploader.

Hope that helps.